# Unbounded operators with dense domain in Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $X$ and $Y$ two Banach spaces,  and let $T: X \rightarrow Y$ be a closed operator. we known that if $T$ with dense domain in hilbert space $X$, then the domain of $T^{*}$ is also dense in hilbert space  $Y^{*}$. Is this result remains true in a Banach space  and why, with justification please.

Comment: Is $T^*$ the transpose of $T$?

Comment: No, $T^{*}$ is the adjoint of $T$. Mr @Will M.

Comment: How do _you_ define adjoint in a Banach space?

Comment: @WillM. Presumably by this way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Definition_for_unbounded_operators_between_normed_spaces

Comment: So it is just the transpose. I believe here is the answer to your question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90197/transpose-of-unbounded-operators-between-banach-spaces

Comment: Thanks @Mr Will M.